# "the average person" or "an average person"?

Tags: articles

Which usage is correct/preferred?

> 1‌. How many words does **the** average person hear a day?
>
> 2‌. How many words does **an** average person hear a day?

Comment: In US English, you would be asking about '*the* average Joe' for the typical American (male).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might expect only the *indefinite* article *(**a, an**)* to be used in such contexts, because we know that in principle there are many individuals who could fit the description ***average, ordinary, typical*** person.

We're only talking about a randomly-selected *one* of those many possibilities, so it seems logical to suppose we should refer to that as ***a*** [possibility]. But idiomatically, native speakers often envisage a single "hypothetical, archetypal" choice fitting the description, which we identify as ***the*** typical example.

Notice that if you've *already identified* who you're talking about, it suddenly becomes somewhat "awkward" to use the definite article...

> *[John is **an** average [person, guy, man, chap, etc.]](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22tell%20me%20which%20books%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22John%20is%20an%20average%22&oq=%22John%20is%20an%20average%22&gs_l=serp.3...6866.7441.6.8540.4.4.0.0.0.0.89.225.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.18.serp.gqor9OVWii8&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.d2k&fp=340a5a63302ed31b&biw=1274&bih=930)* (600 hits in Google Books)
>    *?[John is **the** average [person, etc.]](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22tell%20me%20which%20books%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22John%20is%20the%20average%22&oq=%22John%20is%20the%20average%22&gs_l=serp.3...11103.12310.7.12723.5.5.0.0.0.2.118.406.3j2.5.0...0.0...1c.1.18.serp.k0sEyc76nBs&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.d2k&fp=340a5a63302ed31b&biw=1274&bih=930)* (1 hit, but see below)

Note that the only instance of the definite article above is in a context where "John" himself is just a hypothetical person. The writer just selected a/the typical name John to refer to a/the *average citizen*.

---

It may also be instructive to consider use of the BrE term [man on the Clapham omnibus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_man_on_the_Clapham_omnibus) *- a hypothetical reasonable person, used by the courts in English law where it is necessary to decide whether a party has acted in the way that a reasonable person should*.

We don't normally use this term to describe any actual person - usually we're just "conjuring up" such a person for the purposes of illustrating some statement we're making about what he would think or do (if he actually existed, which strictly speaking he doesn't). The usage figures reflect the fact that he's *only* a single hypothetical individual...

> [***the*** man on the Clapham omnibus](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22tell%20me%20which%20books%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22the%20man%20on%20the%20Clapham%20omnibus%22&oq=%22the%20man%20on%20the%20Clapham%20omnibus%22&gs_l=serp.3...8360.9122.2.9439.4.4.0.0.0.1.151.295.3j1.4.0...0.0...1c.1.18.serp.EspjktTmHDM&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=340a5a63302ed31b&biw=1274&bih=930) (17,700 hits)
>    [***a*** man on the Clapham omnibus](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22tell%20me%20which%20books%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22a%20man%20on%20the%20Clapham%20omnibus%22&oq=%22a%20man%20on%20the%20Clapham%20omnibus%22&gs_l=serp.3...651306.652486.3.652743.4.4.0.0.0.0.94.233.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.18.serp.ilKUddz0hXc&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=340a5a63302ed31b&biw=1274&bih=930) (4 hits)

---

In short, if you're "constructing/evoking" a completely hypothetical individual, it's really a matter of stylistic choice whether you refer to him as ***a*** or ***the*** average [whatever]. But if you're saying that *some specific individual* is in fact ***an*** example who fits that description, you'd nearly always use the indefinite article.

Comment: Thank you so much for such an informative and detailed answer. ♥

Comment: Ah! - that's so *sweet!* How do you manage to make a heart symbol appear in a comment?

Comment: I don't think that it's *so* awkward to say that John is *the* average person, but I agree that using the indefinite article seems better.

Comment: @Daniel: I did temper it by saying ***somewhat** awkward*. Obviously native speakers can and do override that awkwardness sometimes. But Google Books has only 4 instances of [he is **the** average person](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he+is+the+average+person%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), compared to 1350 for [he is **an** average person](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he+is+an+average+person%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). If we're teaching "normal" usage to learners, I think we can forget about "credible, but rarely used" variants like that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I just hold down the Alt key and press the number 3 on the number pad. :)

Comment: If you don't know the keyboard shortcut, you can simply Google [heart character](http://www.google.com/search?q=heart+character&ie=&oe=) (or [up arrow character](http://www.google.com/search?q=up+arrow+character&ie=&oe=), or [bullet character](http://www.google.com/search?q=bullet+character&ie=&oe=), etc), and then copy and paste: ♥ ↑ •

Answer (score 0):

"The well-dressed man wears Dolce Gabbana" is more assertive than "A well-dressed man wears Dolce Gabbana."  This is why the definite article is often seen in advertising.