# "a large number of" vs. "the large number of"

Tags: articles

I would like to know which one is more correct?

1. Our automatic analysis in a large number of real photos will be able to help users to...
2. Our automatic analysis in the large number of real photos will be able to help users to...

Comment: I would use a different preposition (_of_) and the indefinite article: _Our automatic analysis of a large number of real photos..._

Comment: You can use *the* if you've previously introduced *a large number of real photos*, and you are now referring back to that same large number.  If not, you need to use an indefinite article.  (And, as J.R. says, *of*.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["the average person" or "an average person"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7698/the-average-person-or-an-average-person)

Answer (score 2):

It should be

> *of* a/the

The first one would be more appropriate when talking about non-specific number of objects, e.g.:

> Our automatic analysis of *a* large number of real photos .....

The second one would be more appropriate if talking about specific photos. E.g.:

> The data displayed here comes from *the* large number of real photos that we collect.