# choice between 'the' and 'an' here

Tags: articles

This is from [a webpage](https://simpleflying.com/does-sam-chui-get-paid-to-fly/) :

> As such, there is relevance for anyone in these flight reviews, even
> if they aren’t as well known! In fact, his influence and status as the
> world’s most followed aviation YouTuber means he can often get access
> to places **the** average avgeek could not.

I'm confused about the choice between 'the' and 'an' here.

If the writer wants to refer to the previously mentioned "they" in the sentence, using "**the**" would be appropriate.

However, if they mean to refer to an unspecified "any average avgeek," using "an" would be correct.

Comment: It's English idiom. Phrases like "the average person" are often used where you might expect "an average person" etc.

Comment: @ralph.m Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["the average person" or "an average person"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7698/the-average-person-or-an-average-person) (There's also [a similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254576/the-average-person-or-an-average-person) on ELU.)

Comment: @StuartF Yes. Thank you very much.